# Starting fragment from within ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I need bit of help understanding how to start a fragment from within a custom ArrayAdapter. I know how to start it from within my activity but in this case, I need it to start when a button is pressed on a view populated from my custom ArrayAdapter.

I have tried the following:

```
JobDescFragment firstFragment = new JobDescFragment();
((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

And also this, which is really just the long way of writing out my first try:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                JobDescFragment fragment = new JobDescFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

When I run my app and click on the button which is meant to open the fragment, it crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.lorentzos.swipecards.MainActivity
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the context of my activity? I'm not sure what the proper way of opening a fragment is from a custom ArrayAdapter.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

I managed to get around the error message, I was sending the application context instead of the activity context to my adapater.

Now my adapter is presumably being added correctly but I still can't see it. It does not open. Is this because the R.id.fragment_container is on the xml file of the activity and not of the adapter?

Comment: The error states that the context variable references an Application rather than an activity. So maybe you are using the ArrayAdapter constructor wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your context this value :

```
context = getActivity();
```

Then use it in your adapter

```
((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

You should be fine.

Comment: I cant actually use getActivity in the ArrayAdapter since it cannot resolve that method.

Comment: Pass the context in your adapter's constructor and you may use it then.

Comment: Thanks, I have the context in the constructor of the adapter. But I can't seem to be able to use it? I tried removing the (MainActivity) and just using context but that does not work - it cannot find the getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: I managed to get past the error message and presumably the fragment is added, but it still does not open, nothing happens when I click my button except that the toast message is printed. Any idea why the fragment is not opening?

Comment: Yes, I did, the fragment background was set to transparent so I couldn't see it but it was actually there! Thanks for the help!